# Can I use google icons in Freemarker?

Tags: java, css, freemarker

[image]I'm trying to use icons from google but it doesn't work. Is there any way to fix it?

UPDATE:
This my html template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <title>Assessment Report</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  test
</div>
<div>
   <span class="material-icons" style="color: red;">face</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I cannot see the face icon in pdf document

Comment: I don't know Freemarker, but can you somehow use that `link href` in the `head` of the `html` and the `span` in the `body`?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't work. I can we see the icon when I open html template it self, but I can see the icon in pdf, only `face` word

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `link` tag in the `head` and the `span` in the `body` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `<link>` tag between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <span class="material-icons" style="color: red;">face</span>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. The thing is that we use `flying-saucer-pdf` to generate pdf and that library doesn't support external css.
The most relevant solution is [Flying Saucer not reading stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193701/flying-saucer-not-reading-stylesheet)